# Switching case of each letter in a string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;  
    char arr[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)  
        scanf("%c", &arr[i]);  
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {  
        if ('a' <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 'z')  
            arr[i] =-32;  
        else
        if ('A' <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 'Z')  
            arr[i] =+32;  
    }  
    printf("%s", arr);  
    return 0;   
}
```

There was a problem:

You have been given a String consisting of uppercase and lowercase English alphabets. You need to change the case of each alphabet in this String. That is, all the uppercase letters should be converted to lowercase and all the lowercase letters should be converted to uppercase. You need to then print the resultant String to output.

What is wrong with the above code? It is compiling successfully but there is a runtime error.

Comment: And what is the runtime error?  What string are you entering?

Comment: An *obvious* problem is that you don't terminate the string.

Comment: Turn up the warnings on your compiler. I'm sure it will give you warnings at the very least.

Comment: Does the string always contain exactly 100 characters? If not, you should read it with `fgets` instead of 100 `scanf("%c",..)`. This will also add the null terminator for you.

Comment: I was using an online judge and the input was 'abcdE'
The output was ABCDe{@ÿÿÿÿðÿÿ¨ÑdËÀ4¢ËÈA¢Ëý@ ïÿÿ°@
which is definitely wrong

Comment: The runtime error is because `%s` expects `arr` to have a terminating `'\0'`, but it doesn't.    Also, in converting case your code assumes ASCII coding (or compatible) which is not actually guaranteed.   Look up functions `isupper()`, `islower()`, `toupper()`, and `tolower()` which are declared in standard header `<ctype.h>` and are guaranteed to work.

Comment: Also, please try to avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) (like `32` in your code), at least without documenting it. You might also take a look at the [`isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) and [`islower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower) functions, as well as [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) and [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) functions.

Comment: I also used a for loop, to print the characters one by one, The error was the same.

Comment: That's because your code isn't coping with input that is anything other than 100 characters.

Comment: Lastly, if the input is only five characters, why keep reading beyond that? Maybe you should consider using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead? That will give you a nice terminated string to work with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how do I terminate my string if its not 100 letters long and I still want to use scanf?

Comment: BTW, you might want to use `('a'-'A')` instead of `32`... Of course, this is not guaranteed to work on every platform out there (the correct way has already been pointed out by @Peter).

Comment: If you want to use `scanf()` and have the string terminated, use a different format string.   I'll leave it as an exercise to work out what - there is a set of possibilities - and you'll learn more by doing it yourself.

Comment: `if ('a' <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 'z') arr[i] =-32;  ` -> `if (arr[i] >='a' && arr[i] <= 'z') arr[i] = toupper(arr[i]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the main issue is the away you adjust the case: `arr[i] =-32;` does not decrement `arr[i]` by `32`, but stores `32` into `arr[i]`.  The combined assignment operator is spelled `-=`.  You have the same problem for `+=` in the other case.
- Converting lower case to upper case by subtracting `32` works for ASCII, but is not portable to other character sets.  Similarly, comparing to `'a'` and `'z'` works for ASCII, but not for EBCDIC. You should use the functions from `<ctype.h>`.
- you read 100 characters with `scanf("%c"...)` but you do not check the return value, nor do you null terminate the array. Furthermore, you should read at most one less than the size of the array to leave space for the `'\0'` byte. As coded, your program invokes undefined behavior at `printf("%s", arr);` because `arr` is not null terminated.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isupper(c))
            c = tolower(c);
        else
        if (islower(c))
            c = toupper(c);

        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: +1 Okay tbh I really like this answer. Can I unselect the previous answer and select yours as the better one?
Also, why are we declaring c as an int when we will take in characters?

Comment: @KaranSingh:  `c` is defined as `int` to handle all values returned by `getc()`: all values of `unsigned char` plus the special value `EOF`.  The type `char` cannot properly handle all cases. `EOF` will either be the same as `'\377'` (`'ÿ'` in iso-latin1) or will never match.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem is that you are not null-terminating the string, so when you call `printf("%s", arr)` the behavior will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that it never terminates the string. If you read 100 characters, and then you want to print them with `%s` in `printf`, you have to add a null terminator at the end, like this:

```
char arr[100+1]; // See +1
... // Reading code
arr[100] = '\0';
```

Note that library functions `islower`/`isupper` provide a portable, and a lot more readable, approach to testing character type. Similarly, `tolower`/`toupper` provide more information about your intentions to the reader of your code than simply adding and subtracting 32. Moreover, C code that uses these standard functions will work on systems with non-ASCII character encoding.

Comment: what if my string isn't 100 letters long and I still want to terminate it. How do I do that?
and there are a few comments I made under the question.

Comment: @KaranSingh If you want to terminate the string at position `n`, use `arr[n] = '\0';` Writing zero at one position after the last char is all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

In order to `printf("%s", arr)`, you need to terminate `arr` with a null-character.

One way to do it is by:

- Declaring `char arr[101]`
- Setting `arr[100] = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has serveral issues: not-null-terminated input string, unproper lower/uppercase conversion and confusion with =- / -= and =+ / += operators.

Next code is based on yours:

As an alternative to get a null-terminated string it uses fgets() instead of scanf(), just for the example.

Also uses C library functions for avoiding issues with different charsets,  simplifing the conditions and for upper/lower case operations.

*Edited to improve code quality, as @chqrlie suggested in a comment.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i;  
    char arr[101];

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(arr, sizeof(arr), stdin);;  
    for(i=0;i<strlen(arr); i++)  
    {
        int value = (unsigned char) arr[i]; // to properly use int parameters, as expected by ctype.h next functions
        if (isupper(value))
        {
            arr[i]=tolower(value);  
        }
        else {
            if (islower(value))
            {
                arr[i]=toupper(value);
            }
        }
    }  
    printf("%s", arr);  

    return 0;
}
```

Test it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaTNHMGNrS3VVSFE).

Comment: -1 for using unsafe, obsolete function `gets()`.  Furthermore, you use `tolower` and `toupper`, you should also use `islower()` and `isupper()` and cast the `char` argument as `(unsigned char)`. The disclaimer is a lame excuse, use `fgets()`.

Comment: @chqrlie, you're right. As mentioned before I first used gets() to keep the example simple. But I agree with you regarding the (bad) use of deprecated funtions. Edited to use a currently valid alternative.

Comment: I removed the downvote. Note also the problem with signed char arguments to `islower()`, `isupper()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i;
    string str;
    cin >> str;    //Reading input from STDIN
    // cout << "Input number is " << i << endl; // Writing output to STDOUT
    for(i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        if((str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z')||(str[i]>='a'&& str[i]<='z')){
            if(str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z'){
                str[i]=str[i]+32;
                // cout<<str[i];
            }
            
            else if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'){
                str[i]=str[i]-32;
            }
                
            cout<<str[i];   
        }
    }

}
```